# channel entries bulk entry input or import

Tags: channel-entries, bulk

We are moving from another system to EE.  We have over a few dozen to 100s of line items.

Is there a way to add/upload content to expression engine like a database dump or some addon that allows like multiple entries in one interface so you can add all the data in one page?

hope i'm making sense :) lack of sleep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab is normally the go to addon for importing data.

You'll need your data in CSV, Json, or XML format.

I'd suggest doing some trial runs on a test installation so you can get everything working, then apply to your dev site.

Comment: thanks for the reference i'll check it out.  I just find it funny that everything like basic features is a paid upgrade in expression engine.  nothing is like a function of expression engine.